# Is a RESTful API suitable for account creation?

Tags: api, rest, authentication

I am creating a system that requires a user to validate using a SMS Code in order to create an account. The system will have a RESTful API to access the other resources of the system but I am wondering if the account creation stage is suitable for a RESTful API. The high level sequence that I am trying to achieve is:

[image]

If I was to express this using REST Principles I would implement is as follows:

[image]

where RegistrationItem would look like:

```
class RegistrationItem
{
    public string SmsCode {get;set;}

    public int RegistrationId {get;set;}

    public string PhoneNumber {get;set;}
}
```

Does this seem a reasonable design or do account creation and RESTful API's not normally co-exist? I notice that most API's I looked at (facebook, foursquare, twillio) don't seem to support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason you couldn't do account creation from a RESTful API. I might name things differently, but the flow seems reasonable.

Since you asked, I would probably do:

```
POST /registration-requests
-> { "phoneNumber": "555-1212" }
```

The response would have the id. If you're striving for HATEOAS, then it should also have a URI for user creation, either as a Link in the header or as part of the response. Then to create the user,

```
POST /users
-> { "registrationId": 12345, "smsCode": 67890 }
```

and make it return a new user instance. If these APIs can get called from a browser, you should strongly consider using the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks for the response. Are you referring to the naming of RegistrationItem or the properties? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Eric. The concept of linking from registration-request to user was really useful and I have marked this as the answer (especially as I like the Post-Redirect-Get pattern). As a side effect though won't this mean that my user class will always have registrationId and smsCode properties (which were only really relevant at the creation stage)?

Comment: @Fletch Nope. Nothing says you have to add them to the user object that you create. How to exclude them depends on your language/framework.

Comment: oh right, I presumed that all the Verbs were supposed to deal with the same class that represented the underlying Resource. If this is not the case I could pass the registration-request object (or an entirely new class) into a POST /users call and it is just the object created that would be of type User. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. [Nelibur](http://nelibur.org/) could really help you to create appropriate API.

Good tutorial:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/712689/Building-RESTful-Message-Based-Web-Services-with-W

Hope this help;

Answer (score 0):

REST models get, create, update and delete operations.  Register is a type of create operation.  So, yes REST is suitable--unless there's some other criteria or question you have.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Given that, would the Creation of a User resource as a result of a PUT request to a different resource (RegistrationItem) be acceptable? (or should I create a new question for that?)

Comment: You generally hyper link to the things that get created, so if you want clients to know about he user, it may be better to created separately.  But, it depends...